# BigQuery: large gap between creation_time and start_time

Tags: google-bigquery, latency

I have some queries on a materialized view with refresh period 30mins.

I've noticed that most of the queries take ~1000ms, but sometimes, there is a 2000ms gap between the creation_time, and start_time of the jobs, leading to my application waiting 3000ms for the results.

For example, if I query the latest jobs:

```
SELECT
  creation_time,
  IF(user_email = "bigquery-adminbot@system.gserviceaccount.com", "refresh", "query") as type,
  UNIX_MILLIS(start_time) - UNIX_MILLIS(creation_time) start_gap,
  UNIX_MILLIS(end_time) - UNIX_MILLIS(start_time) AS duration,
  total_slot_ms,
  job_id
FROM
  region-US.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT job
WHERE
  (user_email = "bigquery-adminbot@system.gserviceaccount.com" AND query LIKE "%TABLE_NAME%")
  OR (query LIKE "%TABLE_NAME%" AND user_email = "my-project-id-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
ORDER BY creation_time DESC
```

I can see when my query was run, when the refresh on the underlying materialized view was run, and the gap time in my query.

I also checked the monitoring, and it looks like I have plenty of slots and I don't think I'm hitting the ceiling for concurrent queries.

Can anyone tell me what influences the gap between creation_time and start_time? Why would there be a gap? Things I can think of:

- Some sort of computation to do with the materialized view
- Running out of slots
- Running out of concurrent query quota

I can't find much info in the docs.

Comment: For recursive queries I got start_gap of over 4000 ms, but these also run for over one minute. The SQL query has to be translated to map-reduce code and submit to process nodes. This time depends on the resourced available and the complexity of the query. I would not worry about anything under 5 secounds. There are better solutions for data bases, when the data changes in the second range.

Answer (score 0):

The things that you have listed are possible factors for this gap and @samuel 's explaination:

> This time depends on the resourced available and the complexity of the query.

Will post this answer as wiki for better visibility for other users. I will also suggest visiting this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview) for reference for optimizing queries and other plans you can use for optimization.